# Mocking Angular service in Jasmine throws method not found

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oNvsagT8blM694FfYde1?p=preview) I have an Angular/Jasmine test that attempts to mock a service function. The service function mocked needs to be invoked by another function in the service.

This is the error I get:

```
Error: getTheDate() method does not exist
```

And this is my attempt, where the function tested `getTheMonth` should invoke a mocked function `getTheDate`, it seems that `spyOn` is used incorrectly:

```
angular.module("mymodule", [])

.service('myService', function(){

    this.getTheDate = function() {
        return new Date();
    };


    this.getTheMonth = function() {
         var d = this.getTheDate();
         return d.getMonth();
    };
})

describe("Testing date functions", function() {

    beforeEach(function(myService) {
        module("mymodule");
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(12)
        d.setMonth(2);
        d.setFullYear(2018);
        spyOn(myService, 'getTheDate').and.returnValue(d);
    });


    it('should return the month',

        inject(function(myService) {

        expect(myService.getTheMonth()).toEqual(2);


    }));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(function(myService) {
  module("mymodule");
```

should be

```
beforeEach(module("mymodule"));
beforeEach(inject(function(myService) {
```

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2qbqta5AfFVPQPuPWYA?p=preview)